# How to restore Cairo Dock Switcher

Tags: 12.04, cairo-dock

I somehow managed to hide my Cairo Dock Switcher and I can't seem to get it back. Is there a way for me to re-download the applet without re-installing Cairo dock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right Click on Cairo Dock, click on the Add-ons tab then scroll down until you see the Switcher icon. Tick to install.

Comment: My pleasure, *I love Cairo Dock* :)